# Loop dentro de Loop jQuery getJson json

Tags: jquery, json, api, loop

Tenho uma API json e estou tentando montar um layout de modals(BOOTSTRAP).
A parte principal eu consegui que seria a montagem dos modals com a header com o nome da
categoria, agora preciso listar também a subcategoria do json. Segue o exemplo do Json:

```
json 
[
    {
      "id_categoria": "1",
      "categoria": "Despesas Administrativas",
      "subs": [
        {
          "sub": "Adiantamento PJ"
        },
        {
          "sub": "Aluguel"
        },
        {
          "sub": "Comissão",
        },
      ]
    }
  ]

jquery

$.each(json, (key, value) => {
  $dados.append(
    $('<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">')
      .append($('<div class="card m-1">')
        .append($('<div class="card-header bg-dark text-white text-center">').append(value.categoria))
        .append($('<div class="card-body p-0 card-relative" style="height: 40vh; overflow-y: auto">')
          .append($('<table class="table tables table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">')
            .append($('<tbody class="tblSubs">')
              //loop subcategorias relacionadas aqui
              .append($('<tr>')
                .append($('<td class="">').append())
                .append($('<td class="">').append())
              )
            )
          )
        )
        .append($('<div class="card-footer  text-white bg-dark m-0">')
          .append($('<div>').append('DATA'))
          .append($('<div>').append('VALOR'))
        )
      )
  )
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Consegui resolver, mas se você tiver outra ideia..

Criei uma class para salvar um id para o tbody dentro do $.each

var classCategorias = 'categoriaId' + value.id_categoria ;

Criei um for para identificar o id e fazer a inserção dos valores

```
$.each(json, (key, value) => {
    var $subCategoria = $('#'+classCategorias);
    $subCategoria.find('tr').remove();

    for (var i = 0; i < value.subs.length; i++) {
        console.log(value.subs[i].sub);
        $subCategoria.append(
            $('<tr>')
            .append($('<td>').append(value.subs[i].sub))
            .append($('<td>').append(value.subs[i].valor))
        )
    }
})
```

Código completo

```
$.each(json, (key, value) => {
    var classCategorias = 'categoriaId' + value.id_categoria ;
    $dados.append(
        $('<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">')
        .append($('<div class="card m-1">')
            .append($('<div class="card-header bg-dark text-white text-center">').append(value.categoria))
            .append($('<div class="card-body p-0 card-relative" style="height: 40vh; overflow-y: auto">')
                .append($('<table class="table tables table-bordered table-condensed table-striped">')
                    .append($('<tbody id="'+classCategorias+'">')
                        .append($('<tr>')
                            .append($('<td class="">').append('1'))
                            .append($('<td class="">').append('1'))
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            .append($('<div class="card-footer  text-white bg-dark m-0">')
                .append($('<div>').append(mostraBuscaBase))
                .append($('<div>').append(value.valor_total))
            )
        )
    )

    var $subCategoria = $('#'+classCategorias);
    $subCategoria.find('tr').remove();

    for (var i = 0; i < value.subs.length; i++) {
        console.log(value.subs[i].sub);
        $subCategoria.append(
            $('<tr>')
            .append($('<td>').append(value.subs[i].sub))
            .append($('<td>').append(value.subs[i].valor))
        )
    }
});
```